# Calculate difference beween two dates in hours , minutes and seconds

Tags: php, date, time

I have a date with this format

```
Fri Feb 07 17:22:23 +0000 2014
```

How can calculate difference with server current time in php?

I try

```
date('D M d H:i:s Y');
date_diff
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Convert both times to UNIX time (i.e. times since the epoch).

You get the difference in seconds between the two.

Then just do the mathematics

Answer (score 0):

first  and second date time

```
$myd1 =  strtotime('Fri Feb 07 17:22:23 +0000 2014');
$myd2 = strtotime('now');
```

difference

```
$d1 = $myd2 - $myd1;
```

hours minutes seconds as you asked

```
$hours = (int)($d1/3600);
$kalan= $d1 % 3600;
$minutes = (int)(($kalan) / 60);
$seconds = ($d1 % 60 ) ;
```